# 0.12.0 jhipster, hot reloading client code, do not work for me

Tags: gruntjs, jhipster

Intresting framework, but I have problem withe hot reloading on the client side.

Using jhipster 0.12.0

- trying to run 'grunt server'
- imagemin error, then run this 'npm install grunt-contrib-imagemin' to get rid of the problem
- Starts at 0.0.0.0:9000, when I change this to localhost (Gruntfile.js) it seams to work better, no errors at least :-)
- Manually change the main.html file, grunt server detects the change and the chrome browser flashes, but no visible update...

node --version: v0.10.26 npm -version: 1.4.3 grunt -version: v0.4.4
   (grunt), v0.1.13(grunt-cli) bower -version: 1.3.1 yo --version: 1.1.2

BR Jyrg

Answer (score 0):

I did not understand the concept completely with the translate framework.

First you have to edit the "i18n/en.json" then when you modify for example "main.html" the changes will be hot reloaded.